# Hide sections in a word document based on users responses to a series of questions

Tags: c#, ms-word

I'm looking for the best way to achieve the following workflow.

1. Ask a series of questions
2. Captured the responses
3. Use the answers captured to either hide or show certain aspects of word document.
4. Save the complete word document to a location (TBD).

I'm not a developer, so will need to source one who could pick this up, but before I do I wanted to know the best approach to this workflow.

Appreciate any feedback you can offer.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several libraries for interacting with Word (.docx) documents in C#, such as [NPOI](https://github.com/dotnetcore/NPOI) and [DocX](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/DocX), and it is not theoretically complicated to programatically populate a document based on user input and some decision tree and then save it somewhere locally or expose it for download via a web interface. But, keep in mind, that's only part of the solution -- apps have to be hosted, secured, monitored, etc., and that's where the "hard" part is likely to be.

If you are looking to accomplish this within an enterprise environment that uses Microsoft Office 365, you may not need a developer at all. [Microsoft Flow / Microsoft PowerAutomate](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/) allows you to produce complex workflows such as the one you described. There's a very similar one listed here:

https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/galleries/public/templates/3c651e28cded46aab2ba40a2c3116f30/create-word-and-pdf-documents-from-microsoft-forms/